# GeddyJS & socket.io: catching and emitting events from server side

Tags: node.js, socket.io, geddy

i would like to use socket.io along with Geddy. I just followed the instructions in the below link:

https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Getting-started-with-Geddy,-Socket.io,-and-Authentication

Suggest me how to catch the 'connection' event on specific model in server-side.

Also find below the glimpse of  what i have did so far with this model...

```
geddy scaffold -rt LiveUpdate stat:string category:string
```

And found the following auto-generated scripts related to socket.io in "show.html.ejs" of

```
geddy.io.addListenersForModels(['LiveUpdate']);
geddy.model.LiveUpdate.on('update', function (chat) { 
  ....
```

What i actually need is to know how to catch or emit events for this model from the server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emitting socket.io events from models and controllers in Geddy is pretty simple:

- `geddy.io.sockets.emit` will emit an event to all connected clients

If you want to listen for events from, or send events to specific clients, you'll need to create an `after_start.js` file in your app's config directory, and use `geddy.io` like you would normally use `socket.io`:

```
geddy.io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems like this might go in init.js these days.